# select all caching & stream filter vs database query in SpringBoot, Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, caching, query-optimization

Currently I have implemented a cache for **selectAll** method then filter it by a condition by stream filtering on cached list with all elements. Secondary filtered lists caching by conditional values as the key gains some speed but consumes more memory and filter function takes time.

Other way around, typical database filtering on condition is faster but retrieving the data from remote database host is slower. Is there a way to run database queries(other than filtering function) on **selectAll** cache?. So, I can gain more speed while optimizing the memory usage.

Completely different answer is also accepted

Comment: One of the solutions is using [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)  (you may add [PagedResources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/hateoas/PagedResources.html) as well) - getting all items even if using cache is a bit expensive ....

Comment: Databases are optimized for filtering thanks to indices (b-trees, etc). If your dataset is lightweight enough, consider using a file or an in-memory local database as a cache (Derby, H2, HSQL, etc.).